# How to increment in SQL using a trigger?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have a table that holds a list of cuisines and a total of how many restaurants there are with that cuisine. (e.g. Italian | 7)

I'm trying to set-up a trigger in phpMyAdmin that will increment the total every time a new restaurant is added to the database. Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateStats AFTER INSERT ON Restaurant
BEGIN
    UPDATE RestaurantStats SET TotalRestaurants = TotalRestaurants + 1 WHERE Cusine = NEW.cusine;
END;
```

But I keep getting an error message and it's telling me that it has to do with my Syntax. Where am I going wrong? I followed the example I saw pretty well.

Here is the error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN UPDATE RestaurantStats SET TotalRestaurants = TotalRestaurants + 1 WHERE' at line 2
```

Comment: Please share the exact error message. Also, what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: I've update the question to display the error and I'm trying to do this in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Check [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/722fe/1).

Answer (score 2):

do you have to have `for each row`

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateStats 
AFTER INSERT ON Restaurant 
FOR EACH ROW 
    UPDATE RestaurantStats SET TotalRestaurants = TotalRestaurants + 1 WHERE Cusine = NEW.cusine;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use FOR EACH ROW and get rid of the BEGIN...END like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateStats AFTER INSERT ON Restaurant
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE RestaurantStats SET TotalRestaurants = TotalRestaurants + 1 WHERE Cusine = NEW.cusine;
```

BEGIN...END is only used for multiple queries in the same trigger and requires redefinition of the termination character. So your first ; is terminating the statement and leaving the BEGIN open without an END.

Comment: Now I get this error: `#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table' `

Comment: That sounds like you already have another (or the same) trigger defined for that table and event. Run `show triggers` to see what's defined and then drop it by name if already there. I tried the statement in the answer and it works fine.

Comment: @FortunaIwasaki - did that solve the problem for you? If you really need multiple triggers for that same table and event, here is some good info and example: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

try with "for each row":

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateStats AFTER INSERT ON Restaurant
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE RestaurantStats SET TotalRestaurants = TotalRestaurants + 1 WHERE Cusine = NEW.cusine;
END;
```

Haven't tried it myself so not sure if it works...

Comment: Now I get this error:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5`

Comment: @FortunaIwasaki looks like there are some unnecessary white spaces... So on line 5 is `END;`?

Comment: No it's the statement: `UPDATE RestaurantStats SET TotalRestaurants = TotalRestaurants + 1 WHERE Cusine = NEW.cusine;`

I removed the white space ate that start but I get the same error.

Comment: You don't need the BEGIN...END for a single statement and, if you use them, you need to re-define the delimiter. So I suggest that you remove them.

Comment: @BloodWoork - I think it does because the first ; terminates the query leaving the BEGIN open without an END

Comment: @bitfiddler ok nice! So you might form a new answer so can accept the right answer if it works ;)